# Ruby on Rails two create actions to two different controllers simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a Threads controller and Messages controller.

Threads has_many Messages

Once a user clicks send, I send data into Threads controller to create the thread. I want to make it to so that

threads_controller.rb

```
def create
    ...
    if @thread.save
         #send data into messages_controller 
         #to create the corresponding table for a message with this thread_id

end
```

So, essentially I am trying to do two POSTS one after another if the first one succeeds.

I think redirect_to is what I am supposed to use. Is it possible to use redirect_to to pass params and call create action from a different controller?

EDIT:
I have to have a Thread(bad name choice for the reason Ryan mentioned, but for the sake of not confusing people with answers on the bottom, let's keep it) Model and Message Model here. Thread table needs to only take in the message_title. The Message table takes in from_id(id of user sending message), to_id(id of user receiving message), and message_content. I am trying to do all of this in one form that takes in message_title and message_content.

I hope this helps in understanding the question.

Thanks everyone

Comment: This makes no sense, just create a message for the thread.

Comment: Backend should not rely on HTTP commands. If you do it like that, someone could create a thread by sending a post request to your app. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Dave, I am actually trying to create a private messaging solution between two people for my app and I thought that it might be necessary to do it this way in the backend. If it was a thread where everyone could post, I guess I could just create a message.

Comment: Castilho, I think I know what you are saying, but that's how rails handles create action in the back. So I am not sure how else I could do it if I am using rails

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying; so far it just sounds like you're making this more complicated than it really is. Who the message is for should not matter at all, you're using the same parameters regardless of where the message is created.

Comment: I think you are right. I am stil very new to this, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this in the wrong way.

**First: I really hope that you're not calling a model `Thread`, as that would conflict with the Ruby class `Thread`. If you are, choose a different word**.

Now with the "please aim the gun *away* from your foot" message out of the way...

---

You shouldn't be calling out to the `MessagesController` to create a new message for the controller. Instead, you should be using nested attributes in the new thread form:

```
<%= form_for @thread do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :messages do |message| %>
    <%= render "messages/form", :message => message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Inside your `DiscussionThread` (I am assuming the name of it here) model, you would then have these lines:

```
has_many :messages
accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

You may have to add `messages_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` attributes in this model too.

This tells the `DiscussionThread` model that instances can accept attributes for the `messages` association too. In your `ThreadsController` the action would then remain the same.

For more information about nested attributes, I recommend watching the Railscasts on [Nested Forms #1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Nested Forms #2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your advice. I didn't realize that having a model Thread would be a problem. I will use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, all you would need to do is call the create method on the Message model and pass in the relevant information.  So so something like this in your if @thread.save:

```
Message.create(:item_1 => params[:item_1])
```

If you don't want to go this route, you could use nested resources and then let Rails automagically create the new Message when you pass it the correct information.

Comment: thanks Josh, this helps. I don't know why I never thought about this

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to go to another controller. You can either, in threads controller go:

```
@thread.messages << Message.new(...)
```

or do it in the messages controller, which makes more sense to me, since your users are creating messages with thread creation as a side effect. If you send the `thread_id` properly,  in `params[:message][:thread_id]` the association will be made automatically when you create your object:

```
@message = Message.create(params[:message])
```

If you need some other logic to decide which thread a message is associated with, just set the `thread_id` directly:

```
@message.thread_id = current_thread.id # Or Thread.create(...) or whatever
@message.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing your underlying use cases as:

- create new message and thread
- create new message in existing thread
- view message
- view thread and all associated messages

I would suggest a many to many relationship:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

```
# define has and belongs to many relationship

class Message
  has_and_belongs_to_many :threads
end

class Thread
  has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
end

class MessageThread
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :thread
end

# use case: creating a new message and a new thread, showing message

class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.create! :text => params[:text]
    @thread = @message.threads.create!
  end

  def show; @message = current_user.messages.find(params[:id); end;
end

# use case: creating a message in an existing thread

def MessagesThreadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @thread = current_user.threads.find params[:id]
    @thread.messages.create! :text => params[:text]
  end
end

# use case: viewing all messages in a thread

def ThreadsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_thread

  def show
    @thread = current_user.threads.find params[:id]
    @messages = @thread.messages
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks juwiley, your input was a great help